# segmenting list of values

Tags: powershell

I'm writing some code to figure out how to segment a list of values into more manageable chunks. the reason I want to do this is because I'll have about 100,000 live values and I want to minimise the failure risk.

```
$wholeList = 1..100

$nextStartingPoint

$workingList

function Get-NextTenItems()
{
    $workingList = (1+$nextStartingPoint)..(10+$nextStartingPoint)

    $nextStartingPoint += 10

    Write-Host "inside Get-NextTenItems"
    write-host "Next StartingPoint: $nextStartingPoint"
    $workingList
    Write-Host "exiting Get-NextTenItems"
}

function Write-ListItems()
{
    foreach ($li in $workingList)
    {
        Write-Host $li
    }
}
Get-NextTenItems
Write-ListItems
Get-NextTenItems
Write-ListItems
```

I ran the code in the PowerGUI debugger and I've noticed my $nextStartingPoint is resetting to 0 when I exit the Get-NextTenItems function.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Should I also assume that the same thing is happening to $workingList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `Get-NextTenItems` changes its *local* variables. There are several ways to resolve this issue, here are two of them:

1) Specify the variable scopes explicitly (use prefix `script` or `global`). Namely, use that variables as `$script:nextStartingPoint`, `$script:workingList` inside the function.

2) Change the scope of the function on its call. Namely, call the function using the dot operator ("dot-source" the function), i.e. execute it in the current scope. This code works as expected (no other changes needed):

```
. Get-NextTenItems
Write-ListItems
. Get-NextTenItems
Write-ListItems
```

See also

```
help about_scopes
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to use pipelines. One function produces  chunks and the other consumes them.

With this approach you don't need to pollute global/script scope which is not a good idea. Everything needed is kept in the function that needs it.

```
function Get-Chunk
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$collection, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]$count=10
    )
    #temporary array
    $tmp = @()
    $i = 0
    foreach($c in $collection) {
        $tmp += $c                  # add item $c to array
        $i++                        # increase counter; indicates that we reached chunk size
        if ($i -eq $count) {
            ,$tmp                   # send the temporary array to the pipeline
            $i = 0                  # reset variables
            $tmp = @()         
        }
    }
    if ($tmp)  {                    # if there is something remaining, send it to the pipeline
        ,$tmp
    }
}

function Write-ListItems
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$chunk
    )
    process {
        write-host Chunk: "$chunk"
    }
}
```

Test the functions:

```
$wholeList = 1..100
Get-Chunk $wholeList | Write-ListItems
Chunk: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Chunk: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
Chunk: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
Chunk: 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
Chunk: 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
Chunk: 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
Chunk: 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
Chunk: 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
Chunk: 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
Chunk: 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

Get-Chunk $wholeList 32 | Write-ListItems
Chunk: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
Chunk: 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
Chunk: 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
Chunk: 97 98 99 100
```

---

**Update**

I added some comments to clarify things up. Note, that when sending content to pipeline (a) I don't use `return`, because I would jump from the function away. (b) the comma at the beginning wraps content of `$tmp` to array, so it creates new array with one item (which is array of N items). Why? Because in PowerShell there is automatic unrolling, that would unwrap the items from the array and would flatten all the items -> the result would be one big array again.

Example:

```
function Get-Arrays {
  1,2,3
  "a", "b"
  ,(get-date)
  4,5,6
}
Get-Arrays | % { "$_" }
```

This works as expected:

```
function Get-Arrays {
  ,(1,2,3)
  ,("a", "b")
  ,(get-date)
  ,(4,5,6)
}
Get-Arrays | % { "$_" }
```

Comment: thanks for adding this. My PowerShell skills aren't such that I think of using the param keyword. I wasn't thinking of parameterising to this extent as this script exists for a single purpose, though I'm starting to think that the Get-Chunk function could be reused occasionally. And your encapsulation is better than mine, though I'm not sure what ,@tmp is - something for me to find out.

Comment: ... and I thought I was starting to be OK at Powershell... you've brought me crashing down to earth. ;-)

Comment: Don't worry, the unrolling thing is very tricky/advanced. Just keep in mind that there is something in the background. If you see later that some your script processes one item after another instead of an array (what you expect), then this is the case. ..or forget that completely :) Simply - use PowerShell and enjoy it. That's why PowerShell is here. The rest will come.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding answer is OK. But it's not complete, it lets you code somehow *unreadable*. On a pure programming point of view, you've got two other ways to pass parameters to a procedure (or a function) and one of these way allow you to modify your parameter.

**1. Parameters by value (common fashion)**

using this way you document parameters used by your function

```
Function addition ([int]$x, [int]$y) {
  $x + $y
}
```

**2. Parameters by argument (called by reference a kind of pointer)**

Using this way, the last argument can be modified into your function.

```
function addition ([int]$x, [int]$y, [ref]$R) {
 $Res = $x * $y
 $R.value = $Res
}

# usage
addition $A $B ([ref]$C)
```

In your code using the second solution will :

1. Allow you to modify you variable into the function
2. Let know to other readers of the function that this function is able to modify one of her parameter

I hope it helps.

Comment: @JP - thanks for your suggestion. It's probably a bit more complex than I'd like. This is a single use script and seems more like a C# idea. Also, while programming in C#, I tend to object to passing items by ref as they open the way to producing side effects (a functional programming idea that isn't considered desirable).